# Google Cloud Functions - Editing specific data on a webpage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've recently gotten into using Firebase to host my website. And I'd like to display some stats which are fetched from a database call using Google Cloud Functions whenever the page is loaded by a user.

However, I'm unsure how I can insert this data into a tag on my website.

```
    <div class="stats">
        <div class="usersCard">
            <h4 id=users>Users</h4>
            <h1 id="usersVal">INSERTSTATSHERE</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="serversCard">
            <h4 id=Servers>Servers</h4>
            <h1 id="serversVal">INSERTSTATSHERE</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="infectionsCard">
            <h4 id=infections>Infections</h4>
            <h1 id="infectionsVal">INSERTSTATSHERE</h1>
        </div>
```

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.bigben = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false";

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("discord_pandemic");
        dbo.collection("ArrayStats").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result)
            const totalInfections = result[0].total_infections
            const totalUsers = result[0].total_users
            const totalCommands = result[0].total_commands
            const totalLiveInfections = result[0].total_live_infections
            const totalLiveInfectedChannels = result[0].total_live_infected_channels

        });
    });
});
```

As seen above, I have all the code ready. I just do not know how to edit an attribute on my webpage from a Google Cloud Function. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to [call Cloud Functions from within your web app?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

Comment: I'm trying to update a <h1> tag on `pageload`  using exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);

But I can't seem to figure out how I can edit specific elements of a web page when using firebase.

I usually use ```document.getElementById("lol").innerHTML = "lolsss")``` to edit specific elements. But I get a `document is undefined` error.

Comment: That's because the code inside `functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {` runs on the server, so there is no `document` available there. You'll need to call that code from your web app, and then use the response in that web client to update its HTML.

Comment: Interesting. I am currently attempting this now. Thank you :)

Comment: If you have to put your `firebase config` inside of your <script> tag in your HTML page, it contains sensitive information, such as your APIKEY. Doesn't this make it vulnerable to abuse?

Comment: Search is your friend [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=If+you+have+to+put+your+firebase+config+inside+of+your+%3Cscript%3E+tag+in+your+HTML+page%2C+it+contains+sensitive+information%2C+such+as+your+APIKEY.+Doesn%27t+this+make+it+vulnerable+to+abuse%3F), as it leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: Thanks for linking that. Very useful to know :)